# Delphi 'Could not convert variant of type (UnicodeString) into type (Boolean)

Tags: delphi

I have this code to color grid row based on column data (the grid is from devexpress)

```
var
AColumn: TcxCustomGridTableItem;
gs: variant;
begin

  AColumn := (Sender as TcxGridDBTableView).GetColumnByFieldName('COLOR');

  gs := ARecord.Values[AColumn.Index];

  if VarType(gs) and VarTypeMask = varString or varUString then
    AStyle.Color := gs; //<<<----- exception
```

The field `color` is varchar (firebird) contain values like cllime, clred, etc...
but I get error 'Could not convert variant of type (UnicodeString) into type (Boolean)' at the line with exception comment. what should  I change ?

Thanks

Comment: The `AStyle.Color` property is of Boolean type (based on the compiler error). How is the `AStyle` declared ? Anyway, you can use `if VarIsType(gs, [varString, varUString]) then` to check if a value in `gs` is of a certain type.

Comment: @TLama: I don't really know much about variant types, but the `if` part looks suspicious. Can it possibly be correct? [It almost looks like the OP thinks the compiler accepts natural-language input!]

Comment: @TLama `AStyle.Color` is of type TCOLOR and the compiler accept the line why raise an exception ?

Comment: Your logic in the if needs parens. And you can't magically turn a string into a color. You should be using AsString on your field, and then IIRC IdentToColor.

Comment: that would be AStyle.Color := StringToColor(gs); but Error message is not fitting at all...

Comment: The compiler is happy because you asked for runtime type checks. So that's what it gave you.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand indeed the compiler accept it this is why I was confused.

Comment: @bummi indeed the error message is confusing.

Comment: varUstring is not Boolean! So Try it like `if (VarType(gs) and VarTypeMask = varString) or (VarType(gs) and VarTypeMask = varUString) then ...`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would replace your `if` statement with the following. It uses the [`VarIsType`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Variants.VarIsType) function, which is more straight for Variant type checking and it converts string value stored in your Variant variable to color by using the [`StringToColor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Graphics.StringToColor) function:

```
...
if VarIsType(gs, [varString, varUString]) then
  AStyle.Color := StringToColor(gs);
```

Comment: thanks but I am getting access violation with this solution !! I was expecting it to work !!

Comment: That's a different problem. That's because `AStyle` isn't set up right. We cannot see all of your code. This answer is good.

Comment: +1, but a quick look in System.pas shows that `varString or varUString = varUString`. The OP code kludge works. :)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I will check that although this is really all my code